# Vuex not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules, vue-reactivity

I tried to transition from directly using the bindings for my API in a View to putting all that logic in Vuex. I previously just used Vuex to store entities and included the list call as an action. In my view I for example issued the `myAPI.create(...)` call and then dispatched the `list` action. This worked fine.

After my transition, my View does not react to store updates:

`store/modules/vehicles.js`:

```
import vehiclesAPI from "@/api/vehicles";

const vehicles = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    vehicles: []
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_VEHICLES(state, vehicles) {
      state.vehicles = vehicles;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    list({ commit }) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        vehiclesAPI
          .list()
          .then(response => {
            const vehicles = response.data;
            commit("SET_VEHICLES", vehicles);
            resolve(response);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            reject(e);
          });
      });
    },

    create({ commit }, vehicle) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        vehiclesAPI
          .create(vehicle)
          .then(response => {
            resolve(response);
          })
          .catch(e => {
            reject(e);
          });
      });
    }
  },

  getters: {
    vehicles: state => (state.vehicles ? state.vehicles : [])
  }
};

export default vehicles;
```

In my View I map my actions and getters. To create a vehicle I call

```
this.create(this.vehicle);
this.list();
```

Using the Vue DevTools for Chrome I noticed, that the mutation `SET_VEHICLES` from the `list` action does not contain the created vehicle. However, after issuing a reload, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Interestingly it works, when calling `this.list()` in a `setTimeout`. But it does not work when I use the `create()` promises `then` or `finally`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because actions are async by default, and you should use like this:

```
this.create(this.vehicle)
    .then( () => this.list() )
```

Comment: Aww, thanks man! I misused `.then()` and wrote something like `.then(this.list())`. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, callbacks sometimes are confusing :) . Great that's solved!